# Destroy FragmentStatePagerAdapter instance with parent Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am not sure how to ask this. I tried [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412926/viewpager-fragment-loads-even-if-the-parent-fragment-is-not-active/), but I guess I was not clear enough. So, I thought I just write a small App to describe the situation. Please note, the App uses Googles [SlidingTabLayout](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjCsfjZ7Z_RAhWCKJQKHUznC9kQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fsamples%2FSlidingTabsBasic%2Fsrc%2Fcom.example.android.common%2Fview%2FSlidingTabLayout.html&usg=AFQjCNE2Ra2Qi2iZSYuL7so1Vb871F-4UQ&sig2=tFX-AQgNaVLM3Inyj6-Mzg&bvm=bv.142059868,d.dGo).

Long story short, at any point if I click Button1, the `FrameLayout` should contain `Fragment1`, removing `Fragment2` (if exists). Therefore, FragmentViewPager should also be destroyed as `Fragment2`. However, even then if I change the orientation of my device, I get the Toast which is defined in the `onCreate()` method of `FragmentViewPager`.

Why `FragmentViewPager`'s onCreate is called even if `Fragment2` is paused/destroyed? Is it possible that, the Toast of `FragmentViewPager` will not be shown when `Fragment2` is destroyed?

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.abdfahim.testproject;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }


    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.button1:
                    fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    fragment = new Fragment2();
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, v.getTag().toString()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    };
}
```

**Fragment1**

```
package com.abdfahim.testproject;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment1(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Fragment2**

```
package com.abdfahim.testproject;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment2(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        CharSequence titles[]= {"Tab A", "Tab B"};

        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), titles, titles.length);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assigning the Sliding Tab Layout View
        SlidingTabLayout tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        return rootView;
    }

    static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private CharSequence titles[];
        private int numbOfTabs;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabs) {
            super(fm);

            this.titles = mTitles;
            this.numbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabs;

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("displayText", "Inside Fragment 2, " + titles[position]);
            FragmentViewPager fragment = new FragmentViewPager();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return titles[position];
        }

        // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return numbOfTabs;
        }

    }
}
```

**FragmentViewPager**

```
package com.abdfahim.testproject;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FragmentViewPager extends Fragment {

    public FragmentViewPager(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager,container,false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
        textView.setText(bundle.getString("displayText"));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is View Pager Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you use fragment inside another fragment. you use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager. You can call setAdapter() for the ViewPager from onCreateView() or onActivityCreated()

for more detail. have a look at it

[Why it is not possible to use ViewPager within a Fragment? It actually is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088983/why-it-is-not-possible-to-use-viewpager-within-a-fragment-it-actually-is/12090227#12090227)

Comment: Thanks, I have made a little research about getChildFragmentManager() and it seemed like it should really work. But unfortunately, it doesn't. Even if I use getChildFragmentManager(), the child fragments do not get destroyed with the parent.

Comment: then you should keep track of child fragments and remove them manually. As i have read here.. it explains the same issue you are facing. initialization of fragments upon rotation

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551939/correct-way-to-remove-all-child-fragments

Comment: For record, it actually works fine as long as I don't add the parent fragment to backstack while adding to the frame layout. So, I'd say it solved my problem, thanks. I have to find a way to make it work with addtobackstack() functionality, but that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

For every click your `OnClickListener` creates the instance of `Fragment2` and does not create `Fragment1`. That is due to the misuse of [`View#getTag`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()).

In `MainActivity#onCreate`, change the `if` in the definition of `onClickListener` to this(using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3320148/3836051)):

```
switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
```

In your code, in the `if` that is checked upon a click (for example after clicking `button1`) android asks `v` (the clicked `View`) for its tag - but as none was set using [View#setTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) - it returns `null` which is of course not equal to the `String` object created for "button1", thus the `if` reverts to the `else` every time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I have Tag set properly for the buttons in xml file (which is not shown here). And I can assure the buttons are working as intended (ensured with logcat). However, I must say, your suggestion is better, and I am changing to that, BUT the end result remains same.